# Avg. Test Time(sec) in visual studio test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load-testing

I have done a load test to my wcf was hosted service using visual studio 2010 load testing tool.after the test i got below result.[image: Test Result]

can u any one help me to interpret above result.I have search on the internet and i could not be found any helpful description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you opem the [Tests Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404656%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#TheTestsTable) in the `Tables View` there is a column `Test Time`:

> Test Time: The average time to execute the test during the load test
>   run. The units are seconds.

So, the `Avg. Test Time` is the average execution time of all tests.